# File is being locked when I try to execute delete

Tags: c#, windows-services, locking, xmldocument, streamreader

I have a service that reads an xml document from a directory(works OK), saves the data in sql (works OK) and after that I am copying the file to a FINISHED directory (works OK) and deleting the file (NOT working)from the reading directory. The PROBLEM that I have is that the file is being locked when I try to execute the DELETE. Any advise will be appreciated so I can find where the file is being locked.

```
static public Res GetResMn(string FileName)             
XDocument root = null;
using (var file = new FileStream(FileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
            using (StreamReader oReader = new StreamReader(file, Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1")))
            {
                root = XDocument.Load(oReader);
                oReader.Close();
                oReader.Dispose();
            }
```

Here is the code for the copy and delete

```
    void CopyFile(string FileToMove, string MoveLocation)
    {
        try
        {
             System.IO.File.Copy(FileToMove, MoveLocation, true);
            //System.IO.File.Move(FileToMove, MoveLocation);

                File.Delete(FileToMove);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            WriteLogFile("The process failed: {0} " + e.ToString());
        }
    }
```

This is the code when I get the values from the file

```
    var myElement1 = root.Descendants(XName.Get("rnID", @"namespace.2.0")).FirstOrDefault();
    if (myElement1 != null)
    {
        myRPr.rnID = root.Descendants(XName.Get("rnID", @"namespace.2.0")).FirstOrDefault().Value;
    }
```

This is the error that I am getting in my logFile

```
{0} System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'C:\ReadingDirectory\FileName.xml' is denied.
    at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath) at System.IO.File.Delete(String path)
    at OperaWinSrvc.OperaWinSrvc.ReadFiles()
```

I am gettign the same kind of error when I tried the
`System.IO.File.Move`

Comment: Why don't you just delete the file from its original location? Copying the file and then immediately performing a delete is probably being refused because the operating system is buffering the copy, and locking the file while the buffers are being flushed.

Comment: Can you confirm that the Windows account running the service has write permission on the file in your "reading" directory?

Comment: There's no need to call .Dispose and .Close on the reader since you are running inside a using block.

Comment: FYI, you don't need to call Dispose() (which in turn calls Close()) when wrapping the object in a `using` statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing multiple check ups in different places I finally found the solution to my problem. In the service installer I had the Account property set to Local Service, I change it to LocalSystem, reinstall the service and it appears to work now.

Answer (score 1):

Be sure you are calling `.Close()` on the file object prior to attempting a delete and that you have security permissions to delete from that folder as well.

Access Denied is usually a permissions problem, but can occasionally be caused by a file locking condition.